# Play mp3 from code does not trigger QuickTime. Bug in iOS 4.3

Tags: audio, mp3, quicktime, ios4

There is a bug in iOS4.3 then prevents the quick time player from launching when you play a mp3 or m4v file programmatically.

Can anyone advise on how to resolve this?